# Modify angular variable from Protractor test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am writing e2e tests. I am running AngularJS application and as Javascript test runner I am using grunt. Inside my html I have div tag which represents notification alert. This tag is hidden when there are no notifications, and depending of notification type it pops up with green or red color. I would like to test if it´s going to be shown when there are some notications, and if the color is going to be changed depending on notification type. In order to test that I need to update my model values that are exposed on scope. This is my html code:

```
<div id="notificationAlert" ng-repeat="notification in model.notifications" class="alert alert-{{notification.type}}" role="alert">
   <button type="button" ng-hide="notification.type == 'success'" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button> {{notification.msg}}
</div>
```

How can I set model.notifications from my e2e test?

Update: I used evaluate function to set value on html elemement, and there is my current e2e test:

```
'use strict';

 describe('my app', function() {


beforeEach(function(){
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost:9000');
    browser.waitForAngular();
});

describe('home page initialization', function(){

    it('should alert green when success', function(){
        var alert = element(by.id('notificationAlert'));
        alert.evaluate('model.notifications = [{type: "success", msg: "Test Message"}];');
        expect(alert.getAttribute('class')).toEqual("alert alert-success");
    })

   })
});
```

But now my test fails with following error: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("notificationAlert")

Comment: That should be rather done with mocked variables or steps to reproduce either green or red alert rather than changing model by yourself to fit test case need

Comment: Can you provide me some link where should I start. I´ve never done it before. So, I am really not sure how to mock it.

Comment: If the `model.notifications` is based on HTTP response you can mock it on grunt level like in the blog article here http://randonom.com/blog/2014/06/record-mock-and-proxy-http-requests-with-grunt-connect-prism/ if it's strictly front-end behaviour you should reproduce steps in protractor to achieve same behaviour. By setting model directly from tests you risk positive false test where tests passes when they must not